# How to prevent the standard git merge editor from being used in the VS Code terminal?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I like to use the command line for issuing git commands as much as possible, but when a merge occurs, `emacs` is launched per my settings. If this happens in the VS Code Terminal, key bindings are not going to work well. Is there a way to have the VS Code terminal configured so that VS Code itself is used as the merge editor (but only when `git` is called from the VS Code terminal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the `TERM_PROGRAM` in your `~/.bashrc` or for that matter `~/.zshrc` depending on your shell:

```
if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" = "vscode" ]
then
  export GIT_EDITOR="code"
else
  export GIT_EDITOR="emacs"
fi
```

Looking at `man git-commit` you can see how git picks the appropriate editor, and you might want to simply set the `EDITOR` environment variable instead of `GIT_EDITOR` as other programs would benefit from this as well:

```
$ man git-commit | awk '/core.editor/' RS=
ENVIRONMENT AND CONFIGURATION VARIABLES
       The editor used to edit the commit log message will be chosen from the
       GIT_EDITOR environment variable, the core.editor configuration
       variable, the VISUAL environment variable, or the EDITOR environment
       variable (in that order). See git-var(1) for details.
```

Comment: Idk why I though you wore talking about commit messages. I'm not sure if the above would apply to merging?

Comment: I think you can tweak environment variables for VS Code and all parent processes should inherit that, so that script is obsolete.

Comment: `GIT_EDITOR` worked well in my case, due to the precedence you pointed out - thanks! I maintain a form of dotfiles so this is actually useful to me regardless.